# Executar função da mesma classe

Tags: php, html

Já tentei varias formas aqui do site e na net, mais nenhuma carrega a outra função.
Tenho um form que ao enviar ele carrega a classe e function:

```
class editar {
public function selecao_editar() {
//Aqui tem outro form que ao enviar deve carregar a outra função para atualizar o banco.    
}

function update(){
if (isset($_POST['botaoupdate'])) {
....}
}
}
```

Já tentei das seguintes formas:

```
1°
class editar {
    public function selecao_editar(){
        $temp = editar ::update();
        ...
    }

    function update(){
        ...
    }
}

2°
class editar {
    public function selecao_editar(){
        $this-> update();
        ...
    }

    function update(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Poderia explicar sua pergunta melhor?

Comment: Só preciso que a function ao termino, carregue a outra function da mesma classe.

Comment: [cURL - Consumindo webservice com PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141417/45854)

Comment: [Help here! cURL PHP consumindo webservice](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141417/45854)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

***1°***

```
class editar {
    public function selecao_editar(){
        $this::update();
    }

    function update(){
        //FAÇA ALGO
    }
}
```

***2°***

```
class editar {
    public function selecao_editar(){
        $this->update();
    }

    function update(){
        //FAÇA ALGO
    }
}
```

obs: tente deixar os nomes das classes em maiúscula. é uma boa prática altamente recomendada.

Já testei e funcionou ok aqui. Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Me da o seguinte erro quando clico no form dentro da primeira função. Fatal error: Call to undefined method editar::update() in

Comment: Isso significa que você ainda esta usando editar ::update();.   Use o $this::update();

Comment: Pior que estava certo. Estou usando como disse, e continua o erro

Comment: O erro mencionado diz que em algum lugar você esta fazendo isso **editar ::update()**. Isso não existe você tem que encontrar onde está.

Comment: Encontrei o erro. Mais a primeira função contem um POST para a segunda função. E não executa.

Comment: Você precisa passar como parâmetro da função nesse caso.

Comment: Então, consigo chamar a outra função, mais se eu colocar if (isset($_POST['edit'])) {...} na segunda função não executa.

Answer (score 8):

para chamar uma função da classe dentro dela mesma você deve usar o operador `$this`

```
class foo{
    public function minhafuncao1(){
        //...
    }  
    public function minhafuncao2(){
       $this->minhafuncao1();
    }
}
```

Aparentemente você colocou um espaço entre o operador `->` e o nome da função. Não pode fazer isso!

Para chamar uma função de fora da classe, você deve primeiramente instanciar a classe

```
class foo{
    private function minhafuncao1(){
        //...
    }  
    public function minhafunca2(){
       $this->minhafuncao1();
    }
}

$foo = new foo();
$foo->minhafuncao2();
```

Por fim, o operador de resolução(::) de escopo pode ser usado de 3 maneiras:

```
class foo{
    protected function minhafuncao3(){
    }
}

class foo1 extends foo{
    public function minhafuncao1(){
        //...
    }  
    public function minhafunca2(){
       // Se referenciar a propria classe com o operador self
       self::minhafuncao1();
    }
    public function minhafuncao3(){
       // Se referenciar a herança com o operador parent, para fazer a sobrecarga
       parent::minhafuncao3();
       echo 'funcao alterada';
    }
    public static function minhafuncao4(){
       //...
    }
}
// Se referenciar a métodos estáticos     
$var = foo1::minhafuncao4();
```

Porém é mais comum o uso desse operador para chamar constantes definidas para a classe.