# cURL - Consumindo webservice com PHP

Tags: php, java, web-service

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$url_data = "http://localhost:8080/sistema/webservice/agenda/consultarHorariosDisponiveis";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_data);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$parametros = array(
     "idUnidade" => '3',
     "intervaloDuracao" => '10',
     "dataInicio" => "02/08/2016",
     "dataFim" => "04/08/2016",
     "horaInicio" => "08:00",
     "horaFim" => "22:00"
);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parametros);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Testando o webservice com um programa SoapUI está funcionando certinho, porém, quando tento obter um retorno com o php com esse código, no console da minha aplicação em java, está dando NullPointer, a principio os parâmetros não estão indo de forma correta, então acredito que seja apenas um detalhe no meu código, alguma sugestão?

Comment: Não entendi a sua sinalização, se puder explicar agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive o mesmo problema e resolvi utilizando a função [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.http-build-query.php), que gera uma string em formato URL. Da seguinte maneira:

```
$url_data = "http://localhost:8080/sistema/webservice/agenda/consultarHorariosDisponiveis";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_data);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$parametros = array(
     "idUnidade" => '3',
     "intervaloDuracao" => '10',
     "dataInicio" => "02/08/2016",
     "dataFim" => "04/08/2016",
     "horaInicio" => "08:00",
     "horaFim" => "22:00"
);

$data_Post = http_build_query($parametros); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_Post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Se o seu PHP for anterior ao 5.2.0, você vai ter que usar `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($parametros))` como @touchmx disse.

Caso contrário, deve funcionar normalmente.

Fonte: [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16323168/4649737)